# Write a .htaccess line to find and replace part of a URL

Tags: .htaccess

I know there are a few of these, but I can't find one that describes what I want to do.

I've got an page that I want to retire, for example:

```
www.mysite.com/pages/page_old.php?someargs
```

I'd like the _old to be stripped off, so the page goes to

```
www.mysite.com/pages/page.php?someargs
```

I've tried

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/pages/page_old.php$ ^/pages/page.php$ [L,R=301]
```

but it doesn't work.

Worth noting that ?someargs can be any args passed to the page, so this must be flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The leading slash is not at the URI-path tested in the rule, so it can't be in the regex either.

The substitution URL is a plain text string and regular expression characters shouldn't be used as they are passed literally.

You may try this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^pages/page_old.php  /pages/page.php [R=301,NC,L]
```

The query string will be [passed through unchanged](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) to the substitution URL

Comment: Thanks for that, it's still not forwarding though.

Comment: Please make sure the browser's cache is cleared and post the testing URL. It should work. You can see the substitution URL, could you please post it too?

Comment: Where is the .htacces file?

Comment: it's an intranet site, so can't post that.  the .htaccess is in the root folder.

Comment: ah, I've properly cleaned the cache and it's worked (shift+f5 in Chrome wasn't working).